# how does one set default commit options for mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm using Doctrine MongoDB ODM in a Symfony2 application.

How can I set default commit options (such as `safe: 3` and `fsync: true`)?

Ideally I'd be able to do this in my YAML config files, but [the docs seem to indicate this isn't possible](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html).

If I can [get the Configuration object I should be able to set defaultCommitOptions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#flush-options) (like `fsync`) there, but I'm not sure how/when/where to do that.

Comment: Not sure how to do this, but using fsync for all operations will make things really slow. Please rethink about using fsync very selectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [PR #114](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/pull/114), you can use the top-level configuration option `default_commit_options` for this. By default, the bundle will use the same value as ODM, which is `{safe: true}`. Here's a quick example of the supported options:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    default_commit_options:
        safe: 2      # boolean or positive integer for replication
        fsync: false # boolean 
        timeout: 10  # integer >= -1
```

Take a look at the Configuration class and unit tests for the DI extension for more information.

For older versions of DoctrineMongoDBBundle, the Configuration class is registered in the service container, which means you can implement it on your own. Two options for doing so would be to create a compiler pass in your own bundle and add the method call on the service definition or, if that is too complex, access the service instance in your runtime code and call `setDefaultCommitOptions()` directly.

The code of interest is in [DoctrineMongoDBExtension](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/DoctrineMongoDBExtension.php) and the `loadDocumentManager()` method. From there, you can see the service ID assigned for each Configuration instance (one exists for each DocumentManager). I believe you can also fetch a DM's configuration via the `getConfiguration()` method.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I created an issue: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/issues/109 .

Comment: Technically, [Chris Jones](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3765/leek) did, and then I touched it up a bit. I'll edit the above post to describe the new options.